# 1054, 1064 Errors with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetUserByUserID;
Query OK, 0 rows affected


    mysql> DELIMITER $$
    mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserByUserID(IN userID VARCHAR(32))
        BEGIN
            PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT u.*, usg.SCHOOL_GRADE_ID FROM PF_USER u LEFT JOIN PF_USER_SCHOOL_GRADE usg ON u.USER_ID=usg.USER_ID AND u.USER_ID=?';
            SET @a = userID;
            EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        END $$
    DELIMITER ;

mysql> call GetUserByUserID(000E8893F29ED6E84CECCB0FA8B869D1);
ERROR 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'F29ED6E84CECCB0FA8B869D1)' at line 1

mysql> call GetUserByUserID(00100D6243E1E08BC17607E1AB9E3908);
ERROR 1054 : Unknown column '00100D6243E1E08BC17607E1AB9E3908' in 'field list'
```

Comment: you should wrap the value with single quotes since you are passing string, `call GetUserByUserID('000E8893F29ED6E84CECCB0FA8B869D1');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the Stored procedure like:-

```
mysql> call GetUserByUserID('000E8893F29ED6E84CECCB0FA8B869D1');
```